# Arithmetic in Unix shell Script

Tags: shell, math, awk

I would like to calculate the average of columns 2 and 3 on each line, add 1 to this value and print the whole line. Some of the average values will be floating point numbers.

The input file looks like this:

```
chr20 2330559 2330737
chr20 2332853 2333041
chr20 2537555 2537711
```

The output file:

```
chr20 2330648 2330649
chr20 2332947 2332948
chr20 2537633 2537634
```

I've tried various combinations of awk without success. Any suggestions would be great!
Thanks
Harriet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use awk for this:

```
awk '{$2=($2+$3)/2; $3=$2+1}1' file
```

You can also use the `int()` function to ensure that the result is an integer:

```
awk '{$2=int(($2+$3)/2); $3=$2+1}1' file
```

Comment: ahh! after I pasted the comment, (the ninjia one), I pressed the upvote button, then I found it was my own answer!!! here is the place...

Answer (score 2):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{a=($2+$3)/2;$2=a;$3=a+1}7' file
```

it gives

```
chr20 2330648 2330649
chr20 2332947 2332948
chr20 2537633 2537634
```

Comment: Beat you by two characters :p

Comment: @user000001 `sed 's/vim/awk/' <<< "Real Vim ninjas count every keystroke - do you?"`  :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
awk '{ printf("%s %d %d", $1, ($2 + $3) / 2, ($2 + $3) / 2 + 1) }'
```

You didn't give any indication over what should happen when the average is not an integer.

Comment: If the average isn't an integer, I'd still like to print it out as for an integer or to round down. Thanks

Comment: @user1879573 use the `int()` function for that

Comment: @user1879573 In which case, my answer already rounds down to the nearest integer.